# In Java, how do you deal with double quote inside of a CSV that you need to parse

Tags: java, xml, csv, parsing

here is what I want to do,

This my spend.csv file :

```
"Date","Description","Detail","Amount"
"5/03/21","Cinema","Batman","7.90"
"15/02/20","Groceries","Potatoes","23.00"
"9/12/21","DIY","Wood Plates","33.99"
"9/07/22","Fuel","Shell","$56.00"
"23/08/19","Lamborghini","Aventador","800,000.00"
```

From a table view :

[Table View of the csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVpqL.png)

And here is what I want as my output file named spend.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SPEND>
    <RECORD DATE="5/03/21">
        <DESC>Cinema</DESC>
        <DETAIL>Batman</DETAIL>
        <AMOUNT>7.90</AMOUNT>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD DATE="15/02/20">
        <DESC>Groceries</DESC>
        <DETAIL>Potatoes</DETAIL>
        <AMOUNT>23.00</AMOUNT>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD DATE="9/12/21">
        <DESC>DIY</DESC>
        <DETAIL>Wood Plates</DETAIL>
        <AMOUNT>33.99</AMOUNT>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD DATE="9/07/22">
        <DESC>Fuel</DESC>
        <DETAIL>Shell</DETAIL>
        <AMOUNT>$56.00</AMOUNT>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD DATE="23/08/19">
        <DESC>Lamborghini</DESC>
        <DETAIL>Aventador</DETAIL>
        <AMOUNT>800,000.00</AMOUNT>
    </RECORD>
    </SPEND>
```

In order to do that, I found some stuff here and there and managed to get this :

```
    public class Main {
    
       public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
         
            List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    
            File file = new File("spend.csv");
            BufferedReader reader = null;
    
            try {
    
                DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder domBuilder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    
                Document newDoc = domBuilder.newDocument();
                // Root element
                Element rootElement = newDoc.createElement("XMLCreators");
                newDoc.appendChild(rootElement);
    
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                int line = 0;
    
                String text = null;
                while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, "", false);
    
                    int index = 0;
    
    
                    String[] rowValues = text.split(",");
    
                    if (line == 0) { // Header row
                        for (String col : rowValues) {
                            headers.add(col);
                        }
                    } else { // Data row
                        Element rowElement = newDoc.createElement("RECORDS");
                        rootElement.appendChild(rowElement);
                        for (int col = 0; col < headers.size(); col++) {
                            String header = headers.get(col);
                            String value = null;
    
                            if (col < rowValues.length) {
                                value = rowValues[col];
                            } else {
                                value = "";
                            }
    
                            Element curElement = newDoc.createElement(header);
                            curElement.appendChild(newDoc.createTextNode(value));
                            rowElement.appendChild(curElement);
                        }
                    }
                    line++;
                }
    
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
                OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
    
                try {
                    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);
    
                    TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                    Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();
                    aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                    aTransformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                    aTransformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    
                    Source src = new DOMSource(newDoc);
                    Result result = new StreamResult(osw);
                    aTransformer.transform(src, result);
    
                    osw.flush();
                    System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
                } catch (Exception exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        osw.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    try {
                        baos.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
        }
    }
```

At this point the programm should print in the terminal the XML file but;

Sadly, because of the double quotes of each value in my CSV file, I'm having this issue :

java org.w3c.dom.domexception invalid_character_err an invalid or illegal xml character is specified

I think I'm missing something around those lines :

```
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(text, "", false);
    int index = 0;
    String[] rowValues = text.split(",");
```

I would like to keep the double quotes in my CSV, if anyone as an idea feel free to tell me please!

Comment: ["`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) (but I don't think you actually use the `StringTokenizer` you create)

Comment: StringTokenizer st = line do nothing ! The "st" variable isn't used anywhere in your program.

Comment: your program will crash when a value between quotes contains a "," !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run your conversion, do a

```
String.replaceAll("\"", "####")
```

Then run the conversion and when it is complete, reverse it and replace all the "####" in the string with double quotes

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach using OpenCsv and Jackson:

```
public class FileProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<DataStructure> importList =  new CsvToBeanBuilder<DataStructure>(
                new FileReader("pathIn"))
                    .withIgnoreEmptyLine(true)
                    .withType(DataStructure.class)
                    .build()
                    .parse();

        ListLoader exportList = new ListLoader(importList);

        XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlMapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true)
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .writeValue(new File("pathOut"), exportList);
    }
}
```

Class to serialize each element:

```
@Data
public class DataStructure {
    @CsvBindByName
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "DATE")
    private String date;
    @CsvBindByName
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DESC")
    private String description;
    @CsvBindByName
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DETAIL")
    private String detail;
    @CsvBindByName
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "AMOUNT")
    private String amount;
}
```

Class to serialize full list:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "SPEND")
public class ListLoader {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "RECORD")
    private List<DataStructure> list;

    public ListLoader(List<DataStructure> list){
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```